# Separate vassal logging with uWSGI emperor mode

Tags: python, uwsgi

I'm running uWSGI 1.9.17 in emperor mode (with the default config from Trusty's uwsgi-emperor package), and the emperor's logs are piping into /var/log/uwsgi/emperor.log.

The emperor.log file also contains all the stdout/err combined from each vassal, and I can't seem to get any of the vassals to log to a separate file. I've tried using the `logto = /var/uwsgi/apps/vassal1.log` config options but to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea how to get the vassals logging to separate files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To separate vassal logs from emperor, you can use logger:

```
logger = file:/var/uwsgi/apps/vassal1.log
```

I'm not sure why `logto` doesn't work on vassals, but loggers works fine. You can even specify what should be logged to what file (or by using other plugins, not only to file). More on loggers you can find [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Logging.html)

Comment: I tried that too, but then emperor.log contains the error `unable to find logger file` and the vassal is force-restarted (in a cycle).

Comment: Got it working thank to your tip, thank you. An extra step required is to have logfile added to the plugins directive e.g. `plugins = python,logfile`.

Comment: What I find is that option adds master process for every vassal.